# Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 RC from msdnaa will get update to RTM version?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Does anyone know that Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 RC from msdnaa will get update to RTM version and it will be for free?

Answer (score 0):

The final version of Visual Studio 2013 will be [available on October 31st.](https://www.dreamspark.com/Product/Product.aspx?productid=72)